# Aggregate values based on lookup IDs while meeting multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2016

I am given sales data as per "sheet 1" below. Each row contains the quarter, the product, the region ID, and the sales figure. Each region can have multiple IDs, and I have a lookup table (sheet 2) which denote which region each ID belongs to.

My goal is to get to sheet 3. Essentially I am trying to write a formula that will reference the product name in column A, the quarter in cell A1 (which the user will input), and aggregate the relevant sales figures under each region in column B.

I have tried nesting an INDEX & MATCH function within a SUMIFS within a SUMPRODUCT as per below, but I am getting a #VALUE! error:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(sheet1!$D:$D$,MATCH(1,($A4=sheet1!$B:$B)*($A$1=Sheet1!$A:$A),0),0),sheet1$C:$C,sheet2!$A$2:$A$8)*(sheet2!$B$2:$B$8=$B4))`

Does anyone know what is wrong with my formula, or if there is a better approach to this problem?

Sheet 1 (Raw data)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Quarter | Product | ID | 2021 Sales |
| 2 | Q1 | A | 1 | 39 |
| 3 | Q1 | A | 3 | 41 |
| 4 | Q1 | A | 7 | 20 |
| 5 | Q1 | A | 14 | 7 |
| 6 | Q1 | A | 25 | 2 |
| 7 | Q1 | A | 27 | 2 |
| 8 | Q1 | A | 44 | 45 |
| 9 | Q1 | B | 1 | 28 |
| 10 | Q1 | B | 3 | 34 |
| 11 | Q1 | B | 7 | 29 |
| 12 | Q1 | B | 14 | 48 |
| 13 | Q1 | B | 25 | 5 |
| 14 | Q1 | B | 27 | 15 |
| 15 | Q1 | B | 44 | 32 |
| 16 | Q2 | A | 1 | 19 |
| 17 | Q2 | A | 3 | 28 |
|  | and so forth… |  |  |  |

Sheet 2 (region ID lookup table)

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | Region |
| 2 | 1 | East |
| 3 | 3 | East |
| 4 | 7 | Central |
| 5 | 14 | Central |
| 6 | 25 | Central |
| 7 | 27 | West |
| 8 | 44 | West |

Sheet 3 (Report)

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Product | Region | Sales |
| 4 | A | East | 29 |
| 5 | A | Central | 42 |
| 6 | A | West | 31 |

Comment: I wish I could help you with this but, I can give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little rework:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!C:C,IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8=$B4,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8),Sheet1!A:A,$A$1,Sheet1!B:B,A4))
```

Depending on version one may need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

With the dynamic array formula FILTER we can replace the IF() part with FILTER():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!C:C,FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8=$B4),Sheet1!A:A,$A$1,Sheet1!B:B,A4))
```

And it will save a few iterations.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I've never actually used the FILTER function before, so I think I'll stick with the IF() version for now because I understand it (never thought to use it like that). If you don't mind, would you be able to discern what the issue was with my initial formula?

Comment: `INDEX(sheet1!$D:$D$,MATCH(1,($A4=sheet1!$B:$B)*($A$1=Sheet1!$A:$A),0),0)` will only return one value and yet you need it to return an array.  Second problem is that SUMIFS does not allow arrays as ranges, so even if you could get it to return an array the sumifs would not accept it.  And even if you were able to get the SUMIFS to accept the array and the array was correct size and shape, then in the sumproduct you are trying to multiply the resultant array from SUMIFs with another array which is set size and will not be the same size as the resultant SUMIFS array.

Comment: Thanks Scott, what if instead of just 2021 sales I had multiple columns for each year starting on column D. And for example if I only wanted to perform the aggregation on a specified year I would then require the INDEX function to find the correct year's column right?

Comment: That is correct, You would use INDEX to return the correct column in Place of `Sheet1!D:D`  If you have problems getting it to work, ask a new question with what you tried.  You can refer back to this question.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I tried a few attempts to nest the INDEX function within your solution but can't seem to get it to work. Again, I really am not sure why my function is not working. Hoping you can take a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766680/nesting-index-function-within-a-sumproduct-to-aggregate-values-within-the-correc