# Nesting INDEX function within a SUMPRODUCT to aggregate values within the correct column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

This is an adaption to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754579/aggregate-values-based-on-lookup-ids-while-meeting-multiple-criteria) regarding how to aggregate values based on lookup IDs and multiple criteria.

This time I would like to index for the correct year. My goal is to get to sheet 3, where a formula contained in cells C4:D6 will reference the product name in column A, the quarter in cell A1 (which the user will input) and the year in cell C3 & D3, and aggregate the relevant sales figures under each region in column B.

In my previous question, I was provided a solution that would nest a SUMIF within a SUMPRODUCT. I am trying to build on this function by adding an INDEX & MATCH formula within the formula to index for the correct year's column in sheet 1. I have tried the following in the report but am getting a #N/A error.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$F,0,MATCH(C$3,Sheet1!$D$1:$F$1,0)),Sheet1!C:C,IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8=$B4,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8),Sheet1!A:A,$A$1,Sheet1!B:B,A4))`

UPDATE: It has been discovered that the above formula indeed works. This issue was that Sheet 1 was a pivot table, and as such the column headers for each year was in text format, and was different than the formatting of the look up cell in the report, thus there was no link to reference the data.

Sheet 1 (Raw data)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Quarter | Product | ID | 2021 | 2020 | 2019 |
| 2 | Q1 | A | 1 | $12 | $12 | $9 |
| 3 | Q1 | A | 3 | $4 | $30 | $50 |
| 4 | Q1 | A | 7 | $48 | $15 | $39 |
| 5 | Q1 | A | 14 | $42 | $7 | $26 |
| 6 | Q1 | A | 25 | $36 | $50 | $20 |
| 7 | Q1 | A | 27 | $45 | $8 | $9 |
| 8 | Q1 | A | 44 | $12 | $10 | $2 |
| 9 | Q1 | B | 1 | $40 | $32 | $23 |
| 10 | Q1 | B | 3 | $15 | $14 | $30 |
| 11 | Q1 | B | 7 | $21 | $4 | $42 |
| 12 | Q1 | B | 14 | $38 | $26 | $13 |
| 13 | Q1 | B | 25 | $31 | $45 | $9 |
| 14 | Q1 | B | 27 | $32 | $46 | $30 |
| 15 | Q1 | B | 44 | $21 | $40 | $30 |
| 16 | Q2 | A | 1 | $6 | $1 | $43 |
| 17 | Q2 | A | 3 | $12 | $16 | $44 |
|  | and so forth… |  |  |  |  |  |

Sheet 2 (lookup table)

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | Region |
| 2 | 1 | East |
| 3 | 3 | East |
| 4 | 7 | Central |
| 5 | 14 | Central |
| 6 | 25 | Central |
| 7 | 27 | West |
| 8 | 44 | West |

Sheet 3 (Report)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Product | Region | 2021 | 2020 |
| 4 | A | East | $16 | $42 |
| 5 | A | Central | $126 | $45 |
| 6 | A | West | $57 | $22 |

Comment: `$D$1:$F$1` should be `Sheet1!$D$1:$F$1` inside the MATCH

Comment: Hi Scott, you're right. This is actually a typo in my example above as I didn't make this mistake when I tried it on my real case data. However I am still getting an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting #N/A, value not available error.

Comment: The following works for me: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$F,0,MATCH(C$3,Sheet1!$D$1:$F$1,0)),Sheet1!$C:$C,IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8=$B4,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8),Sheet1!$A:$A,$A$1,Sheet1!$B:$B,$A4))`  All I did was add some absolute references.

Comment: Oh, I know.  Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter after editing?  If your version does not support dynamic arrays it must be used.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still receiving the error, I am wondering if it has to do with the format of the headers in sheet 1. Sheet 1 is actually coming from an OLAP cube, and I suspect that those years are in a different format than if you were to just enter 2021 in a cell for example.

Comment: That may be it.  format those cells as general and see.  Also make sure they are not numbers stored as text.  a number will not match a text even if they look the same.

Comment: That does appear to be the culprit. I created separate labels on top of the pivot table and referenced those labels and the data is being pulled correctly. I tried changing the format within the pivot table but doesn't seem to help the issue, but that's probably a separate a question all together. You've been great help, thanks Scott!

Comment: If the data is in a pivot table then the labels are definitely text not numbers.  You can do `MATCH(C$3&"",Sheet1!$D$1:$F$1,0)` to change the number you are searching to text.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I have been searching for a solution to that problem for months if you can believe it. Thank you again Scott!